# Adding Divs in Blocks

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I've created a custom block with Div and P tags in which some have id and class attributes. I've tried use FULL & Filtered html formats for the block body however the id and classes don't show up once I've added the block.

Comment: As you've noticed, The FULL and Filtered HTML filters strip out CSS styles, id's, classes, etc. from the full or filtered tags.  No way around it except to either create a verbatim filter to to create the block in a module.

Comment: how would i create a verabtim filter? would this be done in views?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try change to PHP code which this option appear when you enable php filter in Modules page.

Comment: umm, do this only at great peril

Comment: Oh, I just know this way is peril. Thanks Jimajamma

Comment: Enabled php filter on production site can cause big problems if editor of the site is not careful.

Answer (score 1):

In admin/structure/types/manage/your_content_type/display  (drupal 7 path) make sure field Body has format "Default" selected. If you have any other format those will remove the div ids and classes from the body.